# how to escapexml span tag and paragraph tag coming form webservice values

Tags: web-services

I am getting the value from web service &lt;span  and  &lt;/p&gt; like paragraph tag and span can anybody tell how to escape the character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about [Predefined Entities in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), I think. And then replace each entity to the appropriate value. How to do that: depends on the programming language you use.